# How to edit the id of a form element of a content type?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I have a content type with a text field that I need Javascript to do some work on (when in the content type add/edit form). I prefer to have Javascript identify the form element by it's id so I would like to set the id of the form element to something meaningful.

I've attempted to set the id in with a hook_form_alter() but to no success. If I kint() out the template with the form I do see the id being set in the kint() info however the actual form element html is unchanged. My hook_form_alter():

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_element_name']['#id'] = 'element_name_id';
}
```

Is what I'm attempting possible and if so does anyone know how to do this? Or is there some completely different way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by digging through the kint() statement. Turns out the id is buried deeper in the $form array. Here is what worked for me:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['field_element_name']['widget']['0']['value']['#id'] = 'element_name_id';
}
```